# Finding an upper bound of the error of the CLT with respect to the sample size

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

For
\begin{align}
  \overline{T_k}=\frac{T_1+\dots+T_k}{k}
 \end{align}
being the sample average of the first $k$ samples, with $T_i$ being exponentially distributed, the CLT states, that for $k$ large enough the random variables $\sqrt{k}\left(\overline{T_k}-\mu \right)$ converge to a normal distribution $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2 \right)$ in distribution, i.e
\begin{align}
  \sqrt{k}\left(\overline{T_k}- \mu\right) \to \mathcal{N}\left( 0,\sigma^2\right) \, .
 \end{align}

How could one find an upper bound for the error? Is there a way of expressing the error with respect to $k$?

Comment: You have not stated how you would measure the error that you want to find an upper bound for.   But in general no, if you choose $k$ then I can choose a distribution for the $T_i$s which behaves badly for that $k$.  The central limit theorem works the other way round, choosing the distributions for the $T_i$s before increasing $k$

Comment: @Henry Oh okay, I understand. So the $T_i$s I am working with are exponentially distributed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "error"?

Comment: Also, it might be useful to note that your sample average has an exact distribution, namely a gamma distribution, so you can avoid any error fairly easily

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

Comment: @AsbjørnHolk You are right... I formulated my question wrong. The random variable I want to look at is $\tau_k=T_1+T_2+\dots + T_k$. The CLT gives me the information that $\sqrt{k}(\bar{T_k}-\mu)$ converges to a normal distribution. So I guess I want to know an upper bound on the difference of the distribution of $\tau_k$ and the normal distribution. I hope that makes sense